# Verificar se URL é diferente em PHP

Tags: php

Em JavaScript, podemos verificar se a url é diferente, temos o window.location.href

Ai da pra fazer isso:

```
var urlAtual = window.location.href;
var urlCadastro = "www.teste.com/cadastro";
if(urlAtual != urlCadastro){
  window.location.href = "www.teste.com/login";
}
```

O que tentei, daria certo?

```
$atacadoLogado = $this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn();
$urlDoCadastro = "https://www.meusite.com/cadastro";
$pegarDominio = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$urlAtualizada = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://" . $pegarDominio . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(!$atacadoLogado && $urlAtualizada != $urlCadastro){
    header("Location: https://www.meusite.com/login");
}
```

Comment: Conhece a variável super global `$_SERVER`?

Comment: Não, Anderson, vou pesquisar aqui, obrigado por falar.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar a super global $_SERVER

```
$server = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$endereco = $_SERVER ['REQUEST_URI'];

 $clienteLogado = $this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn();
$urlCadastro = $server.$endereco
if(!$atacadoLogado && !$urlCadastro){
    header("Location: http://www.meusite.com/login");
}
```

[Neste link](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.server.php) você encontra todos os índices e a função de cada um sobre esta super variável $_SERVER.

Comment: Este `SERVER_NAME` não deveria ser `HTTP_HOST`?

Comment: Os dois retornam o localhost do servidor, não difere usar um ou outro

Comment: No link que disponibilizei na resposta isso é facilmente encontrado

Comment: Faz diferença sim. O `SERVER_NAME` não inclui a porta utilizada, enquanto `HTTP_HOST` sim. Se a porta requisitada não for a padrão, ela deve estar presente na URL, ou seja, deve-se utilizar `HTTP_HOST` pois funcionará mesmo que a porta seja diferente da 80.

Comment: Onde você viu isso? pode me mandar o link para poder me atualizar? O que sei sobre o server_name é que o nome do servidor pode ser forjado pelo usuário e se a aplicação depender de segurança ela poderá facilmente ser quebrada.

Comment: Na documentação. A porta utilizada pelo servidor fica armazenada em `SERVER_PORT`, não em `SERVER_NAME`. E o que você quis dizer sobre `SERVER_NAME` ser forjado pelo usuário?

Answer (score 2):

Sim amigo é possivel vamos a um exemplo

```
$url = "https://www.google.com.br";
//Aqui ira pegar o dominio
$dominio= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
//Aqui ira concatenar com o http:// ou https:// e salvar em url

 $urlAtual = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http")."://".$dominio. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
//Verifica se é diferente
if($url != $urlAtual){

echo "Diferente";
}
else{
echo "Não diferente";
}
```

Comment: Utilize `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` para verificar se o protocolo da URL solicitada.

Comment: Obrigado, Anderson. Agora me confundiu com a resposta do Bruno, pôs o seu tem HTTP_HOST e o dele tem REQUEST_URI e SERVER_NAME

Comment: @LucasCarvalho Basicamente oque o request_uri faz é pegar o arquivo contido por exemplo irá carregar o o index, ele irá pegar o nome do arquivo exemplo "www.seusite.com/ index.php" ele irá pegar esse index.php, html enfim oque tiver

Comment: Isso irá depender da url que você quer comparar se ela for https você coloca, se não deixa http mesmo, estou produzindo uma resposta melhor aqui, jaja  eu edito para um modo mais facil mas resumidamente é isso ai @

Comment: Pode olhar minha edição la, Anderson? O codigo abaixo do "O que tentei, daria certo?"

Comment: @LucasCarvalho você confundiu tudo. Reveja as respostas e compare com o seu código.

Comment: Ok, estou relendo aqui. Acho que confundi mesmo.

Comment: Desculpe a demora @LucasCarvalho Estou no trabalho ai ta meio corrido kkk bom mas vamos la para pegar o protocolo http ou https sozinho você pode fazer como na parte editada, Nota: Se estiver testando localmente provavelmente a $_SERVER['HTTPS'] retornará erros

Comment: Acho que isso não é ideal, inclusive pode ser considerado um problema de segurança. O `HTTP_HOST` confia no `Host` do cabeçalho, ele pode ser modificado pelo cliente. [Usar o `SERVER_NAME` é melhor, se ele estiver configurado adequadamente.](https://www.acunetix.com/vulnerabilities/web/host-header-attack).

Comment: @Inkeliz Não acho que o SERVER_NAME Seja melhor, pois como na resposta abaixo o Anderson Comentou, Ele gera conflitos quando a porta é 80 ou 443

Comment: Você considera melhor confiar um host que pode ser alterado pelo usuário? Considerando que use apache e utilize [esta configuração](https://pastebin.com/mKXyVFrv), se usar o cURL como `curl http://127.0.0.1/ -H "Host: blabla.com"` usando o `HTTP_HOST` irá obter `blabla.com`, enquanto se se usar o `SERVER_NAME`, que por mim é preferível, você vai obter `127.0.0.1`, devido a configuração do Apache. A situação é, ou você confia num dado do cliente ou da informação do servidor, por mim confiar no servidor é mais seguro.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss pode ver minha edição agora?

Comment: @Inkefeliz independente de um ou outro é possivel detectar um host, de bobiar até um dns reverse no server name ja pegaria, então não vejo essa "grande" segurança que está vendo, um simples nmap ja barraria essa sua enorme segurança